# Generating url with fields.Url when using Flask-Restful generates BuildError

Tags: python, flask, url-routing, flask-restful

I wanted to adapt the wonderful [Tutorial from Miguel Grinberg](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-using-flask-restful) to create a unittest test-executor. I principally just adapted the code from Miguel to my needs, but I get a problem with generating the uri inside the fields map. As long as I remove the

```
'uri': fields.Url('test')
```

everything works fine, but otherwise I get a Build Error:

```
BuildError: ('test', {'Test_environment_id': 123, 'Test_duration': '0.5 sec', 'Success': 1, 'Failure_count': 0, 'Tested_files': 'Some files', 'Request_id': 1, 'Runs_count': 3, 'Created_on': '01.01.1970', 'Error_count': 0, 'Requester': 'John', 'Skipped_count': 2}, None)
```

I discovered very similar Question here on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619969/two-variable-urls-using-flask-restful) but this did not help me to understand what is wrong with my code.I can use the described work-around from that question, but I would really like to know what am I doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
__author__ = 'karlitos'

from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, make_response, request
from flask.ext.restful import Api, Resource, reqparse, fields, marshal,url_for
from time import strftime
from glob import glob
import os
import sqlite3

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = os.getcwd()
PROJECT_DIRECTORIES = glob('{}/projects/*'.format(CURRENT_DIRECTORY))
# create a sqlite database connection object
db_con = sqlite3.connect('{}unittest.db'.format(CURRENT_DIRECTORY))

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="")
api = Api(app)

tests = [
    {
        'Request_id': 1,
        'Requester': 'John',
        'Created_on': '01.01.1970',
        'Test_environment_id': 123,
        'Tested_files': 'Some files',
        'Test_duration': '0.5 sec',
        'Runs_count': 3,
        'Error_count': 0,
        'Failure_count': 0,
        'Skipped_count': 2,
        'Success': 1
    }
]

"""Structure storing the `Request_id`'s of all test currently running indexed by their `Test_environment_id`'s."""
env_id_of_running_tests = {}

"""Structure serving as a template for the `marshal` function which takes raw data and a dict of fields to output and
 filters the data based on those fields."""
test_fields = {
    'Request_id': fields.Integer,
    'Requester': fields.String,
    'Created_on': fields.String,
    'Test_environment_id': fields.Integer,
    'Tested_files': fields.String,
    'Test_duration': fields.String,
    'Runs_count': fields.Integer,
    'Error_count': fields.Integer,
    'Failure_count': fields.Integer,
    'Skipped_count': fields.Integer,
    'Success': fields.Boolean,
    'uri': fields.Url('test')
}

"""Validation function for the environment-id type which has to be in range [1,100]"""


def env_id_type(value, name):
    if value <= 1 or value >= 100:
        raise ValueError("The parameter '{}' is not between 1 and 100. The value: {} was provided".format(name, value))
    return value


class TestsAPI(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.reqparse.add_argument('Requester', type=str, required=True,
                                   help='No requester name provided', location='json')
        self.reqparse.add_argument('Test_environment_id', type=env_id_type, required=True,
                                   help='Bad environment-id provided, between 1 and 100.', location='json')
        super(TestsAPI, self).__init__()

    def get(self):
        return {'tests': [marshal(test, test_fields) for test in tests]}

    def post(self):
        args = self.reqparse.parse_args()

        request_id = tests[-1]['Request_id'] + 1

        # check if the current Test_environment_id is not under the currently running test
        if args['Test_environment_id'] in env_id_of_running_tests:
            return {'message': 'Another test with the same Environment-ID is still running.'}, 409
        else:
            env_id_of_running_tests[args['Test_environment_id']] = request_id
        test = {
            'Request_id': request_id,
            'Requester': args['Requester'],
            'Created_on': strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'),
            'Test_environment_id': args['Test_environment_id'],
            'Tested_files': 'Some files',
            'Test_duration': '',
            'Runs_count': None,
            'Error_count': None,
            'Failure_count': None,
            'Skipped_count': None,
            'Success': None
        }

        tests.append(test)

        return {'test started': marshal(test, test_fields)}, 201


class TestAPI(Resource):

    def __init__(self):
        self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.reqparse.add_argument('Request_id', type=int, required=True,
                                   help='No Request-ID provided', location='json')
        super(TestAPI, self).__init__()

    def get(self, request_id):
        test = [test for test in tests if test['Request_id'] == request_id]
        print 'Request_ID', request_id
        if len(test) == 0:
            abort(404)
        return {'test   ': marshal(test[0], test_fields)}


api.add_resource(TestsAPI, '/test-executor/api/tests', endpoint='tests')
api.add_resource(TestAPI, '/test-executor/api/tests/<int:request_id>', endpoint='test')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'test' endpoint's route has a parameter `request_id` (with a lowercase initial r), but your test data dict has an entry with the key `Request_id` (upper case initial R). When marshalling the data, flask-restful looks for an entry with the lowercase `request_id` in the test data dictionary in order to construct the URL, but it can't find it because of the case mismatch.

If you change the parameter in the route to uppercase `Request_id` it'll take care of your BuildError for requests to the 'tests' endpoint. But with a request to the test endpoint, you'll then have new easily fixable errors due to similar case mismatches in TestAPI.get().

Answer (score 0):

[How to add fields url for nested output fields in flask restful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453636/how-to-add-fields-url-for-nested-output-fields-in-flask-restful) helps answer the question.

You need to assign the 'test' in fields.Url('test') before returning it.

Happens mostly in POST and PUT